# In Vim, when entering a new tab, how to ignore BufEnter event?

Tags: vim

I have some autocmds which run a Vimscript function.  The function is bound to `TabEnter` and also `BufEnter`.

However when somebody enters a new tab, the function is run several times because both the autocmds fire (and `TabEnter` seems to fire `BufEnter` with the previous "current" buffer before firing it again with the new buffer...I think).

Anyway, how can I just run my function once when somebody enters a new tab?

Comment: `WinEnter` will be fired as well; the events are independent of each other.

Comment: According to the `TabEnter` help, it is triggered after `WinEnter` but before `BufEnter`, hence the behaviour you are seeing. Is there any reason you need the `TabEnter` mapping at all, given that `BufEnter` does the job?

Comment: I use the `TabEnter` event to run the function against each buffer in the newly entered tab.  After doing that I don't need to run the function again when I enter the first buffer on the new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by having:

- `TabLocal` set a tab-local variable on `TabEnter` and then process all the buffers in the new tab
- `BufEnter` look for the tab-local variable; if present, it clears it and does nothing else; if absent, it processes the buffer.

Here's [my code](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter/blob/d420a445363bef98dc50fd622c5c96b202abd605/plugin/gitgutter.vim#L209-L217).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us when exactly your functionality needs to be triggered; maybe your combination of events (`TabEnter` and `BufEnter` are somewhat unrelated; what if the same buffer is displayed in both tabs?) is off, and the problem could be fixed by choosing other events.

Apart from that, you could:

- store the last processed buffer (`bufnr('')`) / window (`winnr()`) / ... in a script-local variable, and short-circuit your function if it's the same
- if the problem is a long delay in your function, store a timestamp (`localtime()`) and short-circuit when too little time passed
- if you have the tab-switching under your control (but you probably don't), `:noautocmd` and `:set eventigore+=...` could remedy this